# Uppy - How do you upload to s3 via multipart? Using companion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, uppy

https://uppy.io/docs/aws-s3-multipart/

Uppy multipart plugin sounds like exactly what I need but I can't see how to do the backend part of things.  The impression I get is that I need to setup a companion to route the upload to S3 but can't find any details on setting up the companion for this.

I can see lots of references about using Companion to fetch external content but none on the multipart S3 uploading.

I neither see anywhere inside Uppy to provide AWS credentials which makes me think Companion even more.

But there are 4 steps to complete a multipart upload and I can't see how providing one companion url will help Uppy.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help or jog me in the right direction.

Comment: So far, this is the biggest downfall of this package. I've been trying for so long to figure this out and the fact that it doesn't seem anyone else has accomplished this, and the docs do not adequately explain how to do this is such a letdown. If you want, I've been trying for awhile now. Check out this page for a hint at a possible direction https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1189#issuecomment-445521442

Comment: I've started another StackOverflow topic related to this with what I've been able to come up with if you're still working on this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201655/configuring-uppy-to-use-multipart-uploads-with-laravel-vue

Answer (score 1):

Providing Uppy a companion URL makes it so that Uppy will fire off a series of requests to `the-passed-url.com/s3/multipart`. You then need to configure your server to handle these requests. Your server will be where your credentials are handled for AWS.

In short when you click the upload button in Uppy, this is what happens:

1. Uppy sends a post request to `/s3/multipart` to create/initiate the multipart upload.
2. Using the data returned from the previous request, Uppy will send a get request to `/s3/multipart/{uploadId}` to generate AWS S3 pre-signed URLs to use for uploading the parts.
3. Uppy will then upload the parts using the pre-signed URLs from the previous request.
4. Finally, Uppy will send a post request to `/s3/multipart/{uploadId}/complete` to complete the multipart upload.

I was able to accomplish this using Laravel/Vue. I don't know what your environment is but I've posted my solution which should help, especially if your server is using PHP.

[Configuring Uppy to Use Multipart Uploads with Laravel/Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201655/configuring-uppy-to-use-multipart-uploads-with-laravel-vue)

Comment: where can I find the documentation on what the responses should look like to these API calls? And is it possible to configure the headers for requests? I would need an API key to be passed to authenticate to API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing code snippets for AWS S3 Multipart [[github](https://github.com/jhanitesh10/uppy)]

If you add Companion to the mix, your users will be able to select files from remote sources, such as Instagram, Google Drive, and Dropbox, bypassing the client (so a 5 GB video isn’t eating into your users’ data plans), and then uploaded to the final destination. Files are removed from Companion after an upload is complete, or after a reasonable timeout. Access tokens also don’t stick around for long, for security reasons.

Setup [companion](https://uppy.io/docs/companion/) server:

1: Setup s3 configuration.

Uppy automatically generates the upload URL and puts the file in the uploads directory.

```
s3: {
      getKey: (req, filename) =>{
        return `uploads/${filename}`;
      },
      key: 'AWS KEY',
      secret: 'AWS SECRET',
      bucket: 'AWS BUCKET NAME',
    },
```

2: Support upload from a remote resource
Uppy handles everything for us. We just need to provide a secret key and token from different remote resources like Instagram, drive, etc.

example: Drive upload

- Generate google key and secrete from google and add it to code
- Add redirect URL for authentication

3: Run node server locally

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const rimraf = require('rimraf')
const companion = require('@uppy/companion')
const app = require('express')()

const DATA_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'tmp')

app.use(require('cors')({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
}))
app.use(require('cookie-parser')())
app.use(require('body-parser').json())
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'hello planet',
}))

const options = {
  providerOptions: {
    drive: {
    key: 'YOUR GOOGLE DRIVE KEY',
    secret: 'YOUR GOOGLE DRIVE SECRET'
    },
    s3: {
      getKey: (req, filename) =>{
    return `uploads/${filename}`;
      } ,
      key: 'AWS KEY',
      secret: 'AWS SECRET',
      bucket: 'AWS BUCKET NAME',
    },
  },
  server: { host: 'localhost:3020' },
  filePath: DATA_DIR,
  secret: 'blah blah',
  debug: true,
}

try {
  fs.accessSync(DATA_DIR)
} catch (err) {
  fs.mkdirSync(DATA_DIR)
}
process.on('exit', () => {
  rimraf.sync(DATA_DIR)
})
app.use(companion.app(options))
// handle server errors
const server = app.listen(3020, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3020')
})

companion.socket(server, options)
```

Setup client:

1: client HTML code:
This code will allow upload from the drive, webcam, local, etc. You can customize it to support more remote places.

- Add companion URL as your above node server running URL(http://localhost:3020)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Uppy</title>
    <link href="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v1.29.1/uppy.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="drag-drop-area"></div>

    <script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v1.29.1/uppy.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    Uppy.Core({
        debug: false,
        autoProceed: false,
        restrictions: {
        maxNumberOfFiles: 5,

        }
    }).
    use(Uppy.AwsS3Multipart, {
        limit: 4,
        companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020'
    }).
    use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
        inline: true,
        showProgressDetails: true,
        showLinkToFileUploadResult: false,
        proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
        target: '#drag-drop-area',
    }).use(Uppy.GoogleDrive, { target: Uppy.Dashboard, companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020' })
    .use(Uppy.Url, { target: Uppy.Dashboard, companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020' })
    .use(Uppy.Webcam, { target: Uppy.Dashboard, companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020' });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```